# office app for ios to sync directly with windows

Tags: ios, office, ipad-app

I'm going to be purchasing an iPad Air 2 128GB WiFi (no cellular) soon and will be using it at University.  I'm going to be using it as a portable device with my Windows (7) PC staying at home.  I'm a huge MS Office fan, but not very happy with the Office 365 applications (both the could-based operations and the subscription costs).  What I'm basically looking for is an app (preferably free, but I don't mind paying for it - just as long as it's say $15 or below) which is completely compatible with MS Office 2013.  Another non-negotiable requirement is that I can sync documents between my PC WITHOUT internet/network connection ie via Bluetooth or the Lightning connector.  Other details I don't really mind.  I've looked at a lot of different solutions, but most fail to describe if they can sync directly between devices.

Summary of requirements:

- Runs on iOS, specifically iPad
- Compatible with MS Office 2013 - at very minimum with **Word, Excel and PowerPoint** - *preferably OneNote also, but not strictly necessary as I've already found an app that would work, but would be nice to have everything centralised in one app*
- Syncronise documents between the iPad and PC (and vice versa) **without use of internet connection**
- Costs up to $15
- No ongoing subscriptions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think [DocumentsToGo](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/documents-to-go-standard-office/id317117961?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4) does exactly this.

It features opening and editing of Office formats for Word, Excel and Powerpoint.
It has both a free and a premium version.
Unfortunately the [Premium version](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/documents-to-go-premium-office/id317107309?mt=8&ign-mpt=uo%3D4) is slightly over budget, it costs $16.99.

Comment: Although over budget, as it meets the other requirements, mainly the compatibility and PC/iDevice Sync I'd be willing to purchase this.  Thanks for the quick response!